# How to install Opencv 3.4.1 + contrib 3.4.1 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I need to build **OpenCV 3.4.1 + OpenCV Contrib 3.4.1 for Visual Studio 2010 (vc10)**.

I have Visual Studio 2010 (x86) on Windows 10 (x64). I need OpenCV libraries for x64 architecture.

This is what I done so far:

- built opencv with cmake, configure it (adding opencv_world ant the path to extra modules of opencv_contrib), and generate choosing visual studio 2010 (Win x64)
- opened OpenCV.sln with VS2010, I started the build (Debug, x64): after ~2 hours, a lot of errors occours (over 7k), so I stopped.

There were a lot of errors:

- errors like `Error 410 error C3646: 'CV_OVERRIDE' : unknown override specifier C:\opencv_contrib-3.4\modules\reg\include\opencv2\reg\mapprojec.hpp 72` (**SOLVED**: my bad, I was mixing opencv 3.4 with opencv-contrib 3.4.1)
- errors like `error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\..\lib\Debug\opencv_world341d.lib'   C:\opencv-341\build\modules\world\LINK` (i'm trying to build opencv_world, it's weird that is searching for it..)

I don't know what i'm wrong. I used pre-built binaries of opencv3.4 with vc14 and vc15 without problems, but I need it for vc10 and with the opencv_contrib.

Any suggests?

Comment: Are you familiar with [c++11] ? `override` is a C++11 keyword, and `CV_OVERRIDE` seems like a hack to support pre-c++11 compilers such as VS2010. `#define CV_OVERRIDE` would fix this error.

Comment: @MSalters I solved the CV_OVERRIDE problem: I mixed opencv 3.4 with opencv-contrib 3.4.1. But, However, I have a LINK problem, I added it to the question.